# Do I need a paid developer account to create free apps?

Tags: 8.0

**I want to make a very simple app for my windows phone.**
*Do i really need to pay & get the 19$ dev account, even if i plan to distribute my app for free ?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, [according to Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windowsphone/help/jj206719%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), a paid developer account is needed to submit any app. You can submit 100 free apps once paid up.

Comment: thank you, read the same part but really wasn't sure though, its really sad when u cant post free apps freely, will leave this question open for a day to see if i get any alternate replies, if no other response by tomorrow, will tick your answer & go find my 19$ :)

Comment: And you still need a paid developer account to distribute them freely.

Comment: @caschw, a night of relentless searching lead me to the same conclusion, i just created my first app yesterday, emulated on my device using vs2012. thanks for your reply, gonna get myself a paid account :P (also thanks a ton for the support you rolling to this community, i keep seeing your answers everywhere in the wp8 stack exchange)

Comment: @Sunny You might want to contact user Lance McCarthy as he is a Nokia Ambassador and sometimes can give out developer tokens.

Comment: @Sunny By the way consider mask this as your answer.

Answer (score 4):

There is [Windows Phone App Studio](http://apps.windowsstore.com/) where you can create simple apps online and is free.  If your app is simple enough, that might work. I haven't personally tried it.

> Windows Phone App Studio lets you swiftly build apps for immediate publishing, testing, and sharing with clients, co-workers, and focus groups. Need to make changes or try variations? With the App Studio it's a snap!

Comment: This is for app creation, and allows one phone to be dev unlocked. Paid dev accounts unlock 3 phones. You cannot distribute your app in the store. A paid account is still needed for that.

Comment: "I want to make a very simple app for my windows phone."

Comment: @jimueller, i hadn't worded the question very clearly, i had meant more along the lines of distributing my developed apps in the app store for free (the word simple there was a bit miss leading) But your awesome to have found an alternative angle to the question that the OP never thought of :)

Answer (score 1):

With Windows Phone App studio you can build apps. And test them on you own device for free. But to publish an app to the store, a paid [Developer Account](http://developer.windowsphone.com/en-us) is required. With this account, you can publish app to both, The Windows App Store and the Windows Phone App Store.

Check this link for [Free Developer Account from Nokia.](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&ved=0CD8QFjAC&url=http://developer.nokia.com/Developer_Programs/Premium_developer_program_faq.xhtml&ei=sXvJUq7-K8m4rgfKy4DQCw&usg=AFQjCNFCgecroVQYjFUywzEwx7okf7h0YA&sig2=jEd9_sr6iP1rtg6XaMVnFg&bvm=bv.58187178,d.bmk)

Answer (score 0):

If you are a student, you can register as a developer to the Windows Store.

Go to [Dreamspark](http://dreamspark.com) and get registered. And then use the statements (https://www.dreamspark.com/Student/Windows-Store-Access.aspx)