# Sharing Phonegap Apps Privately for Windows Phone

Tags: apps

I'm starting with Phonegap and I would like to know how can I share it privately for mobile devices like Windows Phone? And if there is any sharing solution that is free? 
Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do I need a paid developer account to create free apps?](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/2524/do-i-need-a-paid-developer-account-to-create-free-apps)

Comment: You cannot distribute apps outside of the Windows Phone Store.

Comment: If it is free or not isn't my main concern, the answer I seek is if I can distribute an app privately?

Comment: You can distribute it, but it is up to whomever received it to ensure their phones are developer unlocked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Private distribtution is *sort of* available in the store - it allows for an app to be distributed by the store, but not to show up in any searches/etc. It would still need a developer account, but these start at 19 USD (15 GBP) for an individual, and would also allow for your finished apps to be sold to the general public. It is only security through obscurity though, so if there is sensitive information within your app, you'd be advised to have secondary authentication.